# How to set scale_fill_brewer and scale_fill_discrete at the same ggplot bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m trying to create a bar chart, but I´m getting an error like:

> Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill',
>   which will replace the existing scale.

I identified the problem as trying to use two scale_fill functions. If I remove one of them (scale_fill_brewer or scale_fill_discrete), it works.

```
ggplot(df_postgres, aes(x=as.factor(language), y=total/1000, fill=type)) + 
geom_bar(stat='identity', color = 'black')+
geom_text(mapping=aes(label=ifelse(type=='A', (paste(as.character(floor(total/1000)),'K') ), '')), vjust=-0.7,color='black')+
scale_x_discrete(name="Language")+
scale_y_continuous(name="Repos (thousands)")+
scale_fill_brewer(palette='Pastel1')+
scale_fill_discrete(name="Proportion",labels=c("Language","Others"))
```

My question is: how can I set the discrete options AND the nice palette option?
I´m a newbie in R, but can´t find a response to this specific error.

Comment: just give the name and labels arguments from `scale_fill_discrete` to `scale_fill_brewer`. They will be passed on internally - via the `...`

Comment: It works Richard! You should write an answer so that I can accept. It is funny, I have tried the inverse, giving the arguments to scale_fill_discrete :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `...` argument to `scale_fill_brewer` will take arguments that will be passed to `scale_fill_discrete`.

So move your `name` and `labels` arguments to `scale_fill_brewer`, delete your `scale_fill_discrete` and everything should work.